# is it possibe to prevent app modify my /etc/resolv.conf dns

Tags: linux

Recently I facing a problem, technically it bother me for a long time. My Fedora 32 dns config in `/etc/resolv.conf` always  mofidied by an unknown app. the modified config look like this:

```
[dolphin@MiWiFi-R4CM-srv]~/Documents/GitHub/reddwarf-music% sudo cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 192.168.31.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 114.114.114.114
```

what I want the dns conf looks like this:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

I only want the `8.8.8.8` dns. If I modified the `/etc/resolv.conf`, it will be changed to the wrong config, what should I do to make the dns config under control?

Comment: 114.114.114.114 belongs to China Unicom - do they provide you ISP services? 192.168.31.1 is an internal device, is that your internet router? Can you change your internet router settings so that  you have only 8.8.8.8 available? If you're using DHCP addressing, that should get rid of at least one of those. I'd suggest adding also a secondary DNS - if you want to use Google DNS service, the secondary is 8.8.4.4

Comment: But I could not control the /etc/resolv.conf, I tried to change it, but it will be reset in the furture for some unkonwn reason, I just want the dns predicate.@Peregrino69

Comment: Yes, I got that :-) I think your system gets its IP address from your router. Judging by those two addresses the most likely thing happening here is that it gets those two from the router in the same package with the IP address. The way to fix that is to login to the router's management interface, finding the DNS section and changing whatever it shows to the google addresses - but take note of the original settings! Another place which you should check is the DHCP settings; you might have there another place to configure the DNS servers. I really recommend using both primary and secondary.

Comment: You need to note down all the original settings just in case - if your internet connection disappears after changing settings you need to be able to restore the original settings. Alternatively you could change Network Manager to something else, but changing router settings is easier. Or you could configure your system to use static IP address - you should be able then to edit resolv.conf without network manager pitching in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write this to `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`

```
[main]
dns=none
```

It keeps the `/etc/resolv.conf` untouched, as NetworkManager mark it as unmanaged by itself and programs known to it (`unbound`, `dnsmasq` and `systemd-resolved`). From `man NetworkManager.conf`, under section [`Main`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/extra/networkmanager/NetworkManager.conf.5.en#MAIN_SECTION), and key `dns`

```
none: NetworkManager will not modify resolv.conf. This implies rc-manager unmanaged
```

Alternately you can set it to `systemd-resolved` and edit `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` with your preferred DNS servers

```
[Resolve]
DNS=192.162.0.1, 9.9.9.9 # Whatever DNS server IP addresses you want, comma separated.
FallbackDNS=8.8.8.8, 1.1.1.1 # Same as above.
```

Don't forget to enable `systemd-resolved.service` afterward.

Answer (score 2):

The real answer is chattr

Yes, you can prevent NetworkManager to change that file. But what about another application or process?
prevent a file to be altered by anything:

```
chattr +i file
```

allow a file to be altered back:

```
chattr -i file
```

Comment: Good point, `dhcpd` and other programmes can alter the file otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

According to the `dhcpcd.conf` man page,

```
nohook script
    Don't run this hook script.  Matches full name, or prefixed with 2 numbers optionally ending with .sh.

    So to stop dhcpcd from touching your DNS settings or starting wpa_supplicant you would do:-
    nohook resolv.conf, wpa_supplicant
```

So append to your `dhcpcd.conf` (mine is located at `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`):

```
nohook resolv.conf
```

Alternatively running `dhcpcd` with `-C` will should work the same, but is only temporary:

```
dhcpcd -C resolv.conf eth0
```

Comment: Editing the dhcpcd.conf file may not have any impact on DNS settings if NetworkManager is what's managing the network connections.